# Archive displayed on a custom page to be used in menu structure

Tags: wordpress

I would like to direct users to appropriate archive pages from within the menu. If I want this I need a page that I can attach to the menu.

How would I display the exact same stuff as on the archive page (archive.php) on another page so that pagination and functionalities remain the same, but some stuff will be taken from the actual page ? (can create custom page template of course)

- I'll still have to show a sidebar for the page that you visited and not archive's sidebar
- Breadcrumbs path will still have to show current menu item position and not archive page path

To show sidebar from the actual page is of most importance here.

**EDIT**

What I want to achieve is this actually: 
Lets say I have a page

> http://my.page/subpage/something/notifications/

I want that on this page, I can display exactly the same stuff as on the certain archive page which is here:

> http://my.page/subpage/notification/

('notification' is a custom post type here)

I already have a solution that displays all archive stuff on another page (created a page template for that), but its a bit complicated to display title, breadcrumbs and sidebar properly for each page, since some of these should stay the same as they would be, but some should take the value of another site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and assign it to a page. On that page you can use [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) to query the posts you want, like this:

```
global $post;
$posts = query_posts( /* Your args here*/ );

foreach($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);
    // Do your stuff as in archive.php
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: I know that, but how would you get the exact archive page content + structure with pagination and everything?

Comment: Copy it from the archive.php file and change the query/loop to the code above.

Comment: This way the pagination doesn't work, even with $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; I updated the question a bit

Comment: Did you also added $paged to the query_posts() arguments? Can you show the relevant part of your code?

Comment: I did. I also figured out how to show some parts of the default page - by executing query_posts only at the point where you actually need it - when you don't need it and need archive's page data, you can still call wp_reset_postdata() like you shown above and it works. (and using variable to store previous $posts somewhere). If you improve your answer a bit I might accept it as correct

Comment: What do you want me to change? wp_reset_postdata() will restore the $post variable to the original main query.

Comment: You did not mention anything about my two points (showing sidebar from main query and some other stuff from this query etc.)

Comment: And I still did not achieve what I want exactly: see my edited question please